# How to use CheckBox="true" to perform calculations

Tags: javascript

Can I use `if CheckBox1="true"` to perform the following

```
var q=this.getField("Numeric1");
var f=this.getField("CheckBox1");
if (f.value="true")
   if(q.value<4)
     event.value=15;
   else
     event.value=q.value+12;
else
   event.value="";
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why not.... Its that all?

Comment: didn't understood what you mean. there is no connection between the if statement and the rest of your code. you can use the if statement and when true activate the rest of your code if that what you ment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can check the state of a checkbox like so in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked
```

which will evaluate to `true` if the box is checked and `false` if the box isn't.

So modify your `if` statement to condition to look something like this:

```
if (f.checked == true) {
    // evaluate the value of q
}
```

Comment: `=` assigns though, should use `==` or `===`

Comment: Whoops. Fixed the typo. But actually you don't even have to do that since `f.checked` evaluates to a Boolean value anyways. The `if` statement could simply be: `if (f.checked) {}`.

Comment: Please edit your answer, `f.checked == 'true'` returns false, it depends on type conversion of the boolean to a Number, then the string 'true' to a Number too (which returns NaN). See the [*Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) steps 6 then 4. Note that `true == 'true'` and `false == 'true'` both return false.